# Receiving unexpected udp packets in my c# client

Tags: c#, python, macos, sockets

I receive unexpected udp packets when i run the code in windows(both client and server in same system). My client is written in c# and the server is in python.

When i run in the same code in mac i don't have any problem and i receive expected messages(here i opened a port in mac for udp).

client(c#):

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Receiver");
            // This constructor arbitrarily assigns the local port number.
            UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient();
            //udpClient.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpClient.Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 137));
            try
            {
                //IPEndPoint object will allow us to read datagrams sent from any source.
                IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 137);
            string message ;

            do
            {
                // Blocks until a message returns on this socket from a remote host.
                Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
                message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

                // Uses the IPEndPoint object to determine which of these two hosts responded.
                Console.WriteLine("This is the message you received: " +
                                             message);
                //Console.WriteLine("This message was sent from " +
                //                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Address.ToString() +
                //                            " on their port number " +
                //                            RemoteIpEndPoint.Port.ToString());
            }
            while (message != "exit");
            udpClient.Close();
            //udpClientB.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Continue");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

server(python-3.6):

```
import socket
from time import sleep

rx=0 #000
ry=0 #000
rz=0 #000
e=0 #000

UDP_IP = "172.20.10.4"
UDP_PORT = 137
MESSAGE = ""


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                     socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
while(1):
    if (rx<360):
        rx=rx+1
    if ((ry<360) & (rx>=360)):
        ry=ry+1
    if ((rx>=360) & (ry>=360)):
        rx=0
        ry=0
    if (rz<360):
        rz=rz+1
        if (rz>=360):
            rz = 0
    if (e<10):
        e=e+1
        if(e>=10):
            e=0
    #verify rx
    if (rx<10):
        rxs='00'+str(rx)
    if ((rx>=10) & (rx<100)):
        rxs='0'+str(rx)
    if (rx>=100):
        rxs=str(rx)
    #verify ry
    if (ry<10):
        rys='00'+str(ry)
    if ((ry>=10) & (ry<100)):
        rys='0'+str(ry)
    if (ry>=100):
        rys=str(ry)
    #verify rz
    if (rz<10):
        rzs='00'+str(rz)
    if ((rz>=10) & (rx<100)):
        rzs='0'+str(rz)
    if (rz>=100):
        rzs=str(rz)
    #verify e
    if (e<10):
        es='00'+str(e)
    if ((e>=10) & (e<100)):
        es='0'+str(e)
    if (e>=100):
        es=str(e)
    MESSAGE = 'h'+'01'+'rx'+rxs+'ry'+rys+'rz'+rzs+'e'+es
    #sock.sendto(MESSAGE, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    sleep(0.1)
```

Expected message(i receive the below in mac):

This is the message you received: h01rx360ry151rz009e007

I receive the below in windows:

```
This is the message you received: ?{        EJFDEBFEEBFACACACACACACACACACAAA
```

Can someone please letme know where i went wrong with.

thanks in advance

Comment: After some crypting computations in your python server code you do `bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8")`. But in C# client code you treat those bytes as ascii - `Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);`. Try to change that to `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receiveBytes);`

Comment: I made the changes but it failed to obtain expected output.. :(

Comment: Then ensure that no other application sends data to that port. Try to use another port (don't forget to open it in firewall).

Comment: i opened a new port and also tried after disabling firewall

Answer (score 0):

If the udp packets are not associated with your server this might be helpful: https://forum.fortinet.com/tm.aspx?m=106656 and here: https://superuser.com/questions/637696/what-is-netbios-does-windows-need-its-ports-137-and-138-open

Windows is using port 137 for its own services. Try change your port on the Windows device.

Comment: thank you ..#i tried to use port 1900 but i receive nothing if i use any port other than 137 and 138

Comment: I know, that is trivial, but are you sure that firewall doesn't block your app or port (other than 137, 138)?

Comment: I receive nothing even after disabling the firewall.this time i alsoopened a new port and assigned it to udp. :(

Comment: also netstat on port 1900 gave the below                                                  
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*
  UDP    172.20.10.4:1900       *:*
  UDP    [::1]:1900             *:*
  UDP    [fe80::51a4:5ccc:dbba:3cd1%14]:1900  *:*

Comment: This have to be something with network. I have changed port to 10`000 and everything works well.

Comment: can you please let me know the os you use?i use windows 10

Comment: I use W10 (1703) too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having issues with port selection. The packets you see are from Windows. 
You don't need the bind statement. This is a working example I'm using with .net core

```
 internal class Program
    {
        private const int PORT = 5678;

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Packet Forwarding UP!");
            var client = new UdpClient(PORT);
            // can use IPAddress.Any or other IP depending on where they are coming from.
            var ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, PORT); 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting... ");
                var receive = client.Receive(ref ipEndPoint);
                Console.WriteLine(" - Received Data - " + receive.Length);                
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been testing the client with [PacketSender's](https://packetsender.com/) Intense Traffic Generator and confirming traffic with [NirSoft TcpUdpWatch](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/live_tcp_udp_watch.html)

[image: demonstration]